# Performance improvement

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

The following code takes about 3 seconds to evaluate, but it has "only" 1000 values to be computed. I'm solving a problem where I have more than 100,000 values to be evaluated, and it is taking hours to compute.

```
table = Table[Table[RandomInteger[{0, 10}] (x^i + y ^j) , {i, 1, 2}, {j,i,2}], {k, 1, 1000}];
numerical = Table[ParallelTable[table[[i]], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}], {i,1, Length[table]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

How can I speed up the above code?

Comment: You'll have better luck, I think, by adding a description of *what* the end goal is here. As it is, it appears to be a complete mess to make a complete mess, where it will almost certainly turn out there's a direct (and efficient) solution to what you're after...

Answer (score 5):

The original code takes ~200 seconds to run on my computer. This one is about 50 times faster.

```
ParallelTable[Table[Table[RandomInteger[{0, 10}] (x^i + y^j), {i, 1, 2}, {j, i, 2}],{x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}], {k, 1, 1000}]
```

(Update) If you want to use the `table` generated before:

```
numericalA = Transpose[Transpose /@ ParallelTable[table, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*1.27956s, 1000 values*)
numericalB = ParallelTable[Table[table[[i]], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}], {i, 1,Length[table]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*210.042s, 1000 values*)
numericalA === numericalB
(*True*)
```

It seems that `table[[i]]` in the original code is time-consuming. Use lists directly as parameters can usually improve the speed.

Answer (score 3):

[Partial answer]

IF you generate a full tensorial structure, that is, have `j` go from 1 to 2 rather than from `i` to 2, and furthermore make `{x,y}` bounds decimals, then the power sums can be a packed array, and it only need be computed once. The multiplication can be done separately.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 xyPairs = 
    Table[x^i + y^j, {x, 0., 1., 0.1}, {y, 0., 1., 0.1}, {i, 1, 
      2}, {j, 1, 2}];]
dims = Dimensions[xyPairs];
AbsoluteTiming[rn = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, Join[{1000}, dims]];]
AbsoluteTiming[res = Map[#*xyPairs &, rn];]

(* Out[198]= {0.0005027, Null}

Out[200]= {0.00776015, Null}

Out[201]= {0.0643741, Null} *)
```

Now you need to puzzle out how to truncate to get the correct final size.